# Game request sent on facebook to my friend but friend did not get the request

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, apple-push-notifications

In iOS code i have sent game request to my friend but he did not getting the request in his facebook account.

this code I added for game inviting to friend

```
FBSDKGameRequestContent *gameRequestContent = [[FBSDKGameRequestContent alloc] init];

gameRequestContent.message = @"game name"; 
gameRequestContent.title = @"title";

// Assuming self implements <FBSDKGameRequestDialogDelegate>
[FBSDKGameRequestDialog showWithContent:gameRequestContent delegate:self];
```